# Exact Value of a Constant Related to the Quickhull Algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry, euclidean-geometry

> What is the exact value of the infinite sum
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n2^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\right)$$

That constant is related to the [Quickhull algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull) in the following way:

- Assume that the set of points, of which the planar convex hull is to be determined, is "dense" inside and on the boundary of smallest enclosing circle; that means, that the largest empty circle inside the enclosing circle, as well as the distance between adjacent points on the convex hull are neglibly small.
  Assume further that the density of the points inside the smallest enclosing circle is approximately equal everywhere.
  Under these assumptions the number of points of a region inside the circle is approximately equal to the area of that region.
- Estimate under the assumptions, how often points are checked when the Quickhull algorithm is executed.

In case of a circle the Quickhull algorithm

- starts with a diagonal, checking every point once to determine on which side of the diagonal it lies-
- in the $n$th step the points outside a regular $2^n$-gon, but inside the enclosing circle are checked once more
- assuming w.l.o.g. a unit enclosing circle and measure of the checked point set equal to area, the formula yields the measure of point checks expressed as area times number of repeated checks.

Wolframalpha reports an approximate value of $4.70334973...$, which is fairly close to $1.5\pi$ and I wonder if the exact value can be expressed via "elementary" irrational and transcendental numbers.

Comment: The inverse symbolic calculator at http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html gives nothing for the approximate value (which according to pari-gp is 4.703349731112244202...) so I would not be optimistic that there is a formula relating it to more "standard" real constants.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard I also checked the approximate continued fraction expansion and it also looks weird...

Comment: Interestingly, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\right)=\pi$.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan that is fairly obvious because the sequence of triangles between the regular $2^n$gons and $2^{n+1}$gons covers the entire area of the unit circle. But a good remark nonetheless, because it illustrates that a minor difference in a formula may have big consequences.